# Atmospherejs.com repo search unavailable for 3 days now?

Tags: meteor, atmosphere.js

I've just started using [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/), absolutely loving it so far, but having issues with [atmospherejs.com](https://atmospherejs.com).

For the last 3 days (the entire time I've been using Meteor) I haven't been able to search for any packages. Every time I try I get `"SEARCH SERVER UNAVAILABLE, PLEASE TRY AGAIN."`

[image]

Is this a regular thing that is to be expected, maybe due to high traffic, or am I doing something wrong?

Apologies for the non-code related question but I googled and couldn't find any results so I thought I'd ask the community that are using it regularly on here.

Many thanks!

Comment: It's working for me right now. Does the problem persist for you? In the 4 years I've been using Meteor now this has never happened to me. As a work-around you can use `meteor search Your_search_term` on the command line.

Comment: It's working again now but thanks for the cli tip ;)